# Why is my primitive xna square not drawn/shown?

Tags: xna, 3d, windows-phone-7

I have made this class to draw a rectangle, but I cant get it to be drawn, I have no issues displaying a 3d model created in 3dmax, but shown these primitives seems much harder

I use this to create it

```
board = new Board(Vector3.Zero, 1000, 1000, Color.Yellow);
```

And here is the implementation

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Quadro.Models;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Quadro
{
    public class Board : IGraphicObject
    {
        //Private Fields
        private Vector3 modelPosition;
        private BasicEffect effect;
        private VertexPositionColor[] vertices;
        private Matrix rotationMatrix;
        private GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
        private Matrix cameraProjection;

        //Constructor
        public Board(Vector3 position, float length, float width, Color color)
        {
            var _color = color;

            vertices = new VertexPositionColor[6];
            vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, position.Z);
            vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y + width, position.Z);
            vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(position.X + length, position.Y, position.Z);
            vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(position.X + length, position.Y, position.Z);
            vertices[4].Position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y + width, position.Z);
            vertices[5].Position = new Vector3(position.X + length, position.Y + width, position.Z);

            for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                vertices[i].Color = color;
            }

            initFields();
        }

        private void initFields()
        {
            graphicsDevice = SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice;
            effect = new BasicEffect(graphicsDevice);
            modelPosition = Vector3.Zero; 

            float screenWidth = (float)graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
            float screenHeight = (float)graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
            float aspectRatio = screenWidth / screenHeight;
            this.cameraProjection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
            this.rotationMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
        }

        //Public Methods
        public void Update(GameTimerEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Draw(Vector3 cameraPosition, GameTimerEventArgs e)
        {
            Matrix cameraView = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                effect.World = rotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                effect.View = cameraView;
                effect.Projection = cameraProjection;
                graphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, 2, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
            }
        }

        public void Rotate(Matrix rotationMatrix)
        {
            this.rotationMatrix = rotationMatrix;
        }

        public void Move(Vector3 moveVector)
        {
            this.modelPosition += moveVector;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code and it appears to be working on an empty project for the most part. But there are a few things that could make it fail:

1. You need to enable `VertexColorEnabled` on your effect otherwise it will be rendered white:

   ```
   effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
   ```
2. If you don't see the board being rendered you're probably looking at it *from behind*. By default, backfacing polygons are culled so they won't be drawn. Either position your camera so that you're seeing the board from the correct angle, or disable backface culling before rendering with:

   ```
   graphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;
   ```
3. You should be setting your effect properties *before* applying the pass, not after! That could also be the source of the problem if you're rendering other objects before and after the board. And move all the `effect.Property` assignments that you're currently doing *outside* the loop. There's no meaning in them being inside the loop if the values are the same in every pass.
4. This one is optional. Since the `BasicEffect` only uses one pass you can also simplify your rendering code by replacing the loop with a simple:

   ```
   effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
   ```

Comment: I dont get anything even when I add those things :/ I see a white gimplse when I run the game, so it might be rendered a single time, but not sure if thats even this object

Comment: @Mech0z Can you place a copy of the current state of your class in a [Pastie](http://pastie.org/)? You might have missed something, because it did work here. And if possible also the place where you're calling Draw too.

Comment: You can download the project here http://gupl.dk/677248/

Comment: @Mech0z I couldn't run the project but I managed to see the code, and you didn't implement my changes correctly... What I meant for the Draw method was something like this instead: [http://pastie.org/3734886](http://pastie.org/3734886). In particular you're missing step 4 of my list, which is quite important. Step 3 is optional but I added it anyway since it's more simple.

Comment: @Mech0z Also, at least in the version I downloaded I don't see where you're using the Board class. Your board object is a Model3D.

Comment: Sorry must have worked abit futher on the project before zipping :& but these are the parts I have changed http://pastie.org/3735001 and it still just shows me my blue cornflower background as the only thing

Comment: @Mech0z Have you tried moving your camera around?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3017/discussion-between-mech0z-and-david-gouveia)